# Unable to delete a row from a Kendo grid when there is a large amount of data in some of the columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC grid which contains five columns. Some of the rows in two of the columns could contain quite a bit of data, perhaps 500 to 1000 characters. The data is displayed fine but if I attempt to delete the row containing the large amount of data, the callback to my delete function errors out with a 500 server error. My delete function is never getting executed. However, if I attempt to delete a row with a much smaller amount of data, I have no issues.

What can I do to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Show the delete action and perhaps the relevant grid markup.

Comment: If the server is returning 500, the problem is in the back-end.